# How to count the changes in text for a specific element?

Tags: javascript

I have problem writing a code.

I have got function that changes the text of the element every few seconds.

How do i count the changes for that *specific* element without changing the function code for the generator?

```js
function generator() {
  number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
  setTimeout(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = number;
      generator();
    }, 2000);
  })
}
generator();
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Why can't you change the code? I would split it in multiple functions and reorganize it by purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create another function and set its interval to 1 ms. Then check if the previous `innerHTML` doesnot `innerHTML` match the current then increase count.

```js
function generator() {
  number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
  setTimeout(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = number;
      generator();
    }, 2000);
  })
}
generator();
let count = 0;
let elm = document.getElementById("demo");
let lastval = elm.innerHTML;
setInterval(() => {
  if(elm.innerHTML !== lastval){
    count++;
    lastval = elm.innerHTML
    console.log(count)
  }

},1)
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why you can't change the `generator` function .But You could do some Changes inside the `generator` function is easy to achieve you goal.

1. For Each count storing you need  `data-count` attribute in the respected elemnt

```js
function generator(id) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
  if(parseFloat(el.innerHTML) == number){ // if previous and current number is matching.its regenerate the number
    generator(id);
  }else{
    setTimeout(function() {
    el.setAttribute('data-count',parseFloat(el.getAttribute('data-count'))+1) //storing the increment value
      el.innerHTML = el.getAttribute('data-count')+':'+number;
      generator(id);
    }, 2000);
  }
}
generator('demo');
generator('demo1');
```

```html
<p id="demo" data-count=0></p>
<p id="demo1" data-count=0></p>
```

Comment: @downvoter please add comment .Whats wrong with my answer?.its more help full to improve my answer